# What's the use of int hash[a]={0} in c++, how it works?

Tags: c++, c++17

```
for(int i=0; i< a; i++){
            cin>>b;
            arr[i]=b;
        }
        int hash[100]={0}; 
        int i = 0; 
        while (i<a) 
        { 
            hash[arr[i]-1]++; 
            i++; 
        }
        int arr1[a];
        for (int i=0; i<a; i++){
            arr1[i]=hash[i]; 
        }
```

in this code i'm counting the occurrence of each int and storing it in new array. But i don't understand how this hash works, can anyone explain it. I'm not asking about array declaration. I want to understand the algorithm behind the count.

Comment: `int hash[100]={0};` creates an array of 100 ints and sets them all to zero. Is that what you are asking about? If not then please make it clear what you don't understand. If you don't understand the algorithm, then try going through a small example with a pen and paper, you'll soon see how it works.

Comment: @john i got that but can you explain how it counts the occurrence.

Comment: @BharaniDaran Occurrence is counted here: `hash[arr[i]-1]++; `

Comment: Better to ask a new question focused on how the algorithm works since this one is already answered and shouldn't be morphed to something you didn't originally ask about. If you do ask a new question you might consider expanding your snippet to a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks Guys i tried with pen and paper and i've understood it now.

Answer (score 1):

The number `0` in this case is actually useless. It does nothing, except reminding the programmer what it is suppose to do.

```
int a[100]; // creates an array, but leaves the memory uninitiated, you do not know what will be there
int b[100] {}; // creates an array and fills the memory with default values, in this case values are 0
int c[100] {0}; // creates an array, fills the first one with 0 and the rest with default values, but default values are also 0
int d[100] = {0}; // equals sign in this case is there for historical reasons, it is not an assignment operator
```

Comment: ya can you explain the algorithm, i mean how it counts the occurrence.

Comment: @BharaniDaran I am sorry, i have been answering the question that you've asked

Comment: I'm sorry i got it now, i tried with pen and paper now. Thanks

Comment: For completenes: `int e[100] = {};`

Comment: @Aconcagua Then we also need to mention `int f[100]({});` and the one with 0 inside of it. But at that point is just becomes a mess.